# How to declare variable in template of Angular?

Tags: angular, templates

This is source code

```
<div>
{{ getActualData() }}
</div>
<div>
{{ getVirtualData() }}
</div>
<div>
 {{ getActualData() - getVirtualData() }}
</div>
```

This is what I want.

```
<div>
{{ actual = getActualData() }}
</div>
<div>
{{ virtual = getVirtualData() }}
</div>
<div>
{{ actual - virtual }}
</div>
```

Because two functions are complex, I would like to save data temporarily and calculate difference shortly.
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can declare variable in template using **`let`** that will evaluate the function and get the result , using ngIf to actually check if the value is there and assign to the variable

```
<div *ngIf="getActualData(); let actual" > 
<div *ngIf="getVirtualData(); let virtual" > 
 {{actual - virtual}}
</div>
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wwywqm?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: Great!,Would you please explain little about this? I am not sure how function result set to variables.Thanks

Comment: Added explanation above

Comment: it is not working for angular 5. Is there any way to do this for angular 5

Comment: What about if the function returns a bool? If the bool is false, the div won't be shown at all.

Answer (score 6):

you can try :

```
    <div *ngIf="getActualData(); let actual">
      <div *ngIf="getVirtualData(); let virtual">
        {{ actual - virtual }}
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

this is a workaround but should work