# can i save temporally objects in a HTML, angular?

Tags: angular

I have a loop that paints a grid, then from that index of the loop.
I look for an array that returns an array

```
<div *ngFor="let day of columnsOfDays; let d = index">
...
<span *ngFor="let aula of findGroups(d)">{{aula?.name}}</span>
```

This function searches based on the index and returns an array

```
findGroups(d: any) {
    return groups = this.groups.dayWeek.find(dayWeek => {
        return dayWeek.idDay=== d;
    }).aulas;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is something like this

```
"aulas=findGroups(d)" <--- Store temp in html array to use later
<span *ngFor="let aula of aulas">{{aula?.name}}</span>
```

Comment: Why don't you just put `aulas=findGroups(d)` in the ts, and the iterate it?...

Comment: because it's called "n" times, if have a 20 groups findGroups is called 20 times one for each

Comment: So you want to have an Array in the html that hold an array ofd something else, then iterate it, right?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi yes its my plan

Comment: I would just find a better way to have all the data in the ts before, and then iterate the array that contains the second array (Basically an `ngFor` inside an `ngFor`). But you maybe are looking for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48959117/how-to-declare-variable-in-template-of-angular

Comment: That's just what I needed, by chance, is there another way to do it or is that the only one?

Comment: I believe that there could be some tricks that allows you to achieve that. But, as I said, I would find a *ts way* to prepare all the data before iterating it. I'm saying that because, when you compile the code, is converted in javascript, html and css. You can't normally declare variables in a standard `*.html` file, if you want to change something you use js/jQuery, that, *more or less* is like changing something from the *ts*.